# How to hide the top part of a group of image?

Tags: html, css

I want to hide the top part of all the image. I tried using `clip` but that requires the image to be either fixed or absolute. The group of images are of scroll type Is there any way to hide the top part of the image. Below is an example.

```
<style>
    #rightCol{
        overflow-x: hidden;

        overflow-y: scroll;
        max-height: 82vh;
    }
   body{
    overflow:hidden;
    }
</style>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-9" style="padding:0; border:ridge; " id="rightCol">
<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/image_1.jpg') ?>" />
<br>
<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/image_2.jpg') ?>" />
<br>
<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/image_3.jpg') ?>" />
<br>
<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/image_4.jpg') ?>" />
<br>
<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/image_5.jpg') ?>" />
<br>
<img class="img-responsive" src="<?php echo base_url('assets/images/image_6.jpg') ?>" />
<br>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by _hide the top part of all the image_

Comment: Try to provide some example

Answer (score 1):

You can give the `.img-responsive` a negative `margin` to cut off the top.

To prevent a visible overlap, you can add some css to the `br` element.

Example:

```css
#rightCol {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-height: 82vh;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-responsive {
  margin-top: -100px; /* adjust this to change the amount cropped at top */
  display: block;
}

/* acts as spacing between images */
.img-cover {
  position: relative;
  content: '';
  background: white;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9" style="padding:0; border:ridge; " id="rightCol">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/300x300" />
    <br class="img-cover">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/300x300" />
    <br class="img-cover">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/300x300" />
    <br class="img-cover">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/300x300" />
    <br class="img-cover">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/300x300" />
    <br class="img-cover">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="https://placehold.it/300x300" />
    <br class="img-cover">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ya this was close. But the next image is coming on top of the previous image with a little white break of 5px